# Using systemd to start gpg-agent?

Tags: gnupg, systemd

I've read up a little on systemd, but still can't quite figure out how to use it to automatically start `gpg-agent` on login.  I gather I'd use `systemctl --user`, but constructing the `gpg-agent.service` has me stumped.  Any and all pointers are welkcome.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that Roland W's answer was true in 2014, but with today's version of gpg-agent, such elaborate configuration seems no longer necessary. At least on Arch Linux, setting up gpg-agent with systemd is as simple as running:

```
systemctl --user enable --now gpg-agent.socket
```

This will cause gpg-agent to be started on-demand by systemd, and it will keep running in the background.

Answer (score 1):

The `gpg-agent` command starts a daemon, but programs that use it expect certain environment variables (`GPG_AGENT_INFO` and `GPG_TTY`) to be set so they know how to communicate with the agent. You have to somehow propagate these from the service script to your shells. The `gpg-agent` MAN page contains a snippet that starts the daemon and writes a shell code fragment to a file in the user's home

```
gpg-agent --daemon --write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
```

You can put this line into as shell script and call it from your service file

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=script-file.sh
<...>
```

The `.gpg-agent-info` file has to be sourced from every shell. The MAN page recommends

```
if [ -f "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then
  . "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"
  export GPG_AGENT_INFO
fi

GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

in your `.profile` file to do this. Information on how to write systemd service files can be found in the systemd.service MAN page.

Comment: Yes, that much is clear from reading the man page, but isn't there some way of getting `gpg-agent` started so that its environment variables makes it into the login session?

Comment: @Magnus I think you can do what you want by sourcing .gpg-agent-info from $HOME/.xprofile   I use bash as my session command processor (and interactive shell), thus I *source* my .bashrc from both my .profile and .xprofile files. Then in my .bashrc I have a division: all that should go into the session environment comes first, then I add this test "[[ $- != \*i\* ]] && return" (no quotes) that detects if it is a non-interactive shell and exits, and all the settings that should go into an interactive environment go at the end of the file.

Comment: I hope u do update this answer because --write-env-file is absolete command